# In Ubuntu 16.04 not start rpcbind on boot

Tags: nfs, systemd

Service rpcbind not start normally on boot in Ubuntu 16.04

```
root@HZ-Saturn /etc/systemd # systemctl status rpc-statd.service
● rpc-statd.service - NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rpc-statd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

root@HZ-Saturn ~ # journalctl /sbin/rpcbind 
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-05-12 12:09:23 CEST, end at Thu 2016-05-12 14:54:54 CEST. --
May 12 12:16:51 HZ-Saturn rpcbind[1738]: rpcbind: xdr_/run/rpcbind/rpcbind.xdr: failed
May 12 12:16:51 HZ-Saturn rpcbind[1738]: rpcbind: xdr_/run/rpcbind/portmap.xdr: failed
```

If I start to manually

```
systemctl start rpcbind
```

It's working.

```
root@HZ-Saturn ~ # systemctl start rpcbind
root@HZ-Saturn ~ # systemctl status rpcbind
● rpcbind.service - RPC bind portmap service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/rpcbind.service.d
           └─50-rpcbind-$portmap.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-05-12 15:13:50 CEST; 2s ago
 Main PID: 1497 (rpcbind)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 512)
   Memory: 528.0K
      CPU: 4ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/rpcbind.service
           └─1497 /sbin/rpcbind -f -w

May 12 15:13:50 HZ-Saturn systemd[1]: Starting RPC bind portmap service...
May 12 15:13:50 HZ-Saturn rpcbind[1497]: rpcbind: xdr_/run/rpcbind/rpcbind.xdr: failed
May 12 15:13:50 HZ-Saturn rpcbind[1497]: rpcbind: xdr_/run/rpcbind/portmap.xdr: failed
May 12 15:13:50 HZ-Saturn systemd[1]: Started RPC bind portmap service.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

It's bug systemd config rpcbind unit in Ubuntu 16.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rpcbind/+bug/1558196

Solution:

```
systemctl add-wants multi-user.target rpcbind.service
```

Comment: I also had to do "systemctl add-wants multi-user.target rpcbind.service" before my ubuntu system stopped asking for a password when I tried to mount from nfs server as user.

Comment: this did not resolve the `rpcbind.xdr: failed` error on my Ubuntu 16.04.1  I get the same error messages in syslog but the service does start on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

The above is not a solution.  **As of this post Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Xenial still has not implemented a solution**.  I have run this patch successfully for a month in a multi-user environment.  I located the below patch from the previous posters link, but the link has since been removed.

The patch can be found here:

[rpcbind patch for 0.2.3-0.2 on 16.04](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/262663140/rpcbind_0.2.3-0.2_0.2.3-0.4.diff.gz)

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, installing nfs-kernel-server will also work to fix this as the nfs-kernel-server service bridges the missing networking service dependencies.

Of course you have to be willing to have a nfs server running on the machine.